# update the listview after inserting a new record with simpleCursorAdapter - requery()

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I understand the `requery()` mechanic, but i do not understand the implementation:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        datasource = new pollDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();

        Cursor values = datasource.getAllCategorie();

        String[] categorieColumns =
            {
                MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NOME   // Contract class constant containing the word column name

            };


            int[] mWordListItems = { R.id.categoria_label };


        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                getApplicationContext(),               // The application's Context object
                R.layout.single_list_item,             // A layout in XML for one row in the ListView
                values,                                // The result from the query
                categorieColumns,                      // A string array of column names in the cursor
                mWordListItems,                        // An integer array of view IDs in the row layout
                0);                                    // Flags (usually none are needed)


        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }




      public void onClick(View view) {
          categorie categoria = null;
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.add:

            categoria = datasource.createCategoria("pluto") ;
          break;


        case R.id.categoria_label:


          break;

        }

      }
```

after the `categoria = datasource.createCategoria("pluto");` i have to define another:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    getApplicationContext(),               // The application's Context object
                    R.layout.single_list_item,             // A layout in XML for one row in the ListView
                    values,                                // The result from the query
                    categorieColumns,                      // A string array of column names in the cursor
                    mWordListItems,                        // An integer array of view IDs in the row layout
                    0);                                    // Flags (usually none are needed)


            setListAdapter(adapter);
```

**PollDataSource**:

```
public class pollDataSource {
    // Database fields
      private SQLiteDatabase database;
      private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
      private String[] allCategorieColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,
          MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PREF, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NOME };   
      private String[] allSondaggiColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,
              MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CATID, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DOMANDA };   
      private String[] allRisposteColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID, 
              MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SONDID, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_RISPOSTA, 
              MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SELEZIONATA };


      public pollDataSource(Context context) {
            dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
          }

      public void open() throws SQLException {
            database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
          }

      public void close() {
            dbHelper.close();
          }

      public categorie createCategoria(String categoria) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NOME, categoria);
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PREF, 0);
            long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CATEGORIE, null,
                values);
            Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CATEGORIE,
                allCategorieColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
                null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            categorie newCategoria = cursorToCategorie(cursor);
            cursor.close();
            return newCategoria;
          } 

      public void deleteCategoria(categorie categoria) {
            long id = categoria.getId();
            System.out.println("Categoria cancellata, id: " + id);
            database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CATEGORIE, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID
                + " = " + id, null);
          }

      public sondaggi createSondaggio(String domanda, int catid) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DOMANDA, domanda);
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CATID, catid);
            long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SONDAGGI, null,
                values);
            Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SONDAGGI,
                allSondaggiColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
                null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            sondaggi newSondaggio = cursorToSondaggi(cursor);
            cursor.close();
            return newSondaggio;
          }


      public void deleteSondaggio(sondaggi sondaggio) {
            long id = sondaggio.getId();
            System.out.println("Sondaggio cancellato, id: " + id);
            database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SONDAGGI, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID
                + " = " + id, null);
          } 

      public Cursor getAllCategorie() {
            List<categorie> categorie = new ArrayList<categorie>();

            Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CATEGORIE,
                allCategorieColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
              categorie categoria = cursorToCategorie(cursor);
              categorie.add(categoria);
              cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            // Make sure to close the cursor
           // cursor.close();
            return cursor;
          }


      private categorie cursorToCategorie(Cursor cursor) {
          categorie categorie = new categorie();
          categorie.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
          categorie.setPreferita(cursor.getLong(1));
          categorie.setNome(cursor.getString(2));
            return categorie;
          }
      private sondaggi cursorToSondaggi(Cursor cursor) {
          sondaggi sondaggi = new sondaggi();
          sondaggi.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
          sondaggi.setDomanda(cursor.getString(1));
          sondaggi.setCatid(cursor.getLong(2));
          return sondaggi;
          }


}
```

with the same inputs?? so basically I will have the same exact code in two different places of the same class... May I define a... "procedure" or a class? I'm sorry if I'm too naive, I'm a real noob at this :D

Comment: add pollDataSource class as well.

Comment: do you want to show data addition/deletion from ListView?

Comment: yes, actually, when i press the "add" button, it adds categories, but i can view them only by restarting the activity, as the listview is updated only in the onCreate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the `requery` cursor method is deprecated. but you're right you have to reload the cursor and then make sure that your new cursor is being presented to your `ListView`. for a quick 'n dirty solution, I suggest you make your adapter a field. and then use the following method:

```
private void requery() {
    Cursor values = datasource.getAllCategorie();
    adapter.changeCursor(values);
}
```

What it does is remake a cursor. then by calling `changeCursor` you swap the old cursor for the new one and the old one is closed automatically. at the very least, you save yourself from making a new adapter. The more sophicated approach with all the trim and fixes i suppose would be to implement a `CursorLoader` which would perform the process automatically when the database content has been changed.

Comment: thanks, I try this now, actually, i have made a copy of the simpleadapter part in the onclick class...