# Android refresh Spinner

Tags: android, dataset, refresh, spinner

How to refresh the dataset of a spinner?
This is my code:

```
mCategory = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_categoryType);
    String[] mCategoryProjection = { DailyTables.TABLE_CATEGORIES_COLUMN_ID, DailyTables.TABLE_CATEGORIES_COLUMN_TITLE };
    int[] to = new int[] {  android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text1 };
    Cursor mCategoryCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(DailyContentProvider.CATEGORIES_CONTENT_URI, mCategoryProjection, null, null, null);
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mCategoryCursor, mCategoryProjection, to, 0 );
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
    mCategory.setAdapter(adapter);
    mCategory.setOnLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnLongClickListener() { 
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) { 
            Cursor currentItem = (Cursor) mCategory.getSelectedItem();
            if( currentItem != null ) {
                 Log.d("", currentItem.getString(currentItem.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DailyTables.TABLE_CATEGORIES_COLUMN_TITLE)) + " is long clicked");
                 DialogFragment newFragment = SpinnerEditCategoryDialogFragment.newInstance( currentItem.getInt(currentItem.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DailyTables.TABLE_CATEGORIES_COLUMN_ID)) );
                 newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
            }
            ((SimpleCursorAdapter) mCategory.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true; 
        } 
     });
```

If I long press the spinner a dialog is opened which renames an item in the spinner. So it would be nice if it would show the right values.
`notifyDataSetChanged()` doesn't do the job. 
What's wrong?

Comment: i answered a similar query here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034770/using-notifydatasetchanged-on-simplecursoradapter-does-not-work#comment19388194_14034770

Comment: you don't have to put the sequence in `onResume` just any event handler that you needed. the important part was that calling `notifyDataSetChanged();` on a `SimpleCursorAdapter` won't give you the results you want.

Comment: Since I don't call another activity the onResume method is not called if I close the DialogFragment. 
I'm in a Fragment and override the onResume with the following code:
     if( mCategoryAdapter != null) {
     String[] categoryProjection = DailyTables.TABLE_CATEGORIES_AVAILABLE_COLUMS;
  Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(DailyContentProvider.CATEGORIES_CONTENT_URI, categoryProjection, null, null, null);
  mCategoryAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);
     }
super.onResume();
So your advice works perfectly if I turn the display on/off but not for my situation.

Comment: The notifyDataSetChanged() method in onLongClick is called before the Dialog is shown. (mistake) So it can't work this way at all. 
How to implement a callback after the onLongClick finished? So I could call the changeCursor variant. Any idea?

Comment: so the issue is that you can't replace the cursor in the OnLongClickListener() because the dialog is shown *after* every time?

Comment: Yes. I can call the cursor replace in the Dialog if the input is done and I pressed OK. Like:
RecordDetailFragment attachedFragment = (RecordDetailFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.record_detail_container);
     if(attachedFragment != null) {      attachedFragment.refreshData();
} 
It works, but I think its ugly..