# Item appears in listview ONLY after I reopen the app

Tags: android, listview

I'm making a ShopingList app now, and I'm using SQLite database to store data and I'm experiencing a problem: when I try to add some item to the listview, I have it appeared in the list only after reopening app. Here is the piece of code which is responsible for adding items in list view.

```
edtxt.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                if (event.getAction()== KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                        String name = edtxt.getText().toString();
                        dbcon.insertData(name);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        edtxt.setText("");
                        return true;

                    }
                }
               return false;
            }
        });
```

Have you any ideas? If you need some another piece of code, please feel free to ask me. Thank you all in advance!

UPDATE: Everything worked! What I did is called getLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad(); in onCreate() method, and added getLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad(); after every change I did to list, like Delete, Edit etc.

Comment: Your adapter contains the data to fill the list with. When you call notifyDataSetChanged you are notifying the adapter that THAT DATA has changed and thus it needs to refresh the list. You are obviously not giving the new data to the adapter, just to the database.

Comment: So, how can I give new data to the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are adding a row to your DB, but you are not updating your cursor.

Edit:

This is a better answer: 
[update the listview after inserting a new record with simpleCursorAdapter - requery()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953171/update-the-listview-after-inserting-a-new-record-with-simplecursoradapter-requ/13953470#13953470)

Answer (score 0):

you have to add your data ex: name to your adapter data set and then call notifyDataSetChanged on your adapter!
you add your data in database and tell adapter that it's data is updated but adapter's data set is not changed here!